# loading tif image into picture box

Tags: vb.net, filenotfoundexception

I am new to VB.net and have been able to write a test program from a user guide to display a .TIF in a picture box when selecting it from a dialog box. But when I try to select a TIF or another other type JPG, GIF etc from a file name I get the error:

> System.IO.filenotfoundException occurred in System.Draawing.dll"

Here is my code:

```
PicTif.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\test.tif")
```

Comment: that means...well, a file of that name cannot be found at that location

Answer (score 0):

Check your spelling and see if the file does exist. You can protect your code.

Imports:

```
Imports System.IO
```

Code:

```
Dim path As String = "c:\test.tif"
If File.Exists(path) Then 
  PicTif.Image = image.FromFile(path)
End If
```

Comment: backslash not fore...and prolly wise to add the import directive